# $\int_{\mathbb R} f dt = 1 = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac f h dt \to h \equiv 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, measure-theory, functions

$$\int_{\mathbb R}  f dt = 1 = \int_{\mathbb R}  \frac f h dt \to h \equiv 1?$$

The context is [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739767/system-of-differential-equations-with-cdfs-and-pdfs?noredirect=1#comment5660913_2739767), and I want to know if this can be generalised hoping to use as few properties of pdfs or cdfs as possible and to use as little measure theory as possible.

We have for all $t \in \mathbb R$,

- $f \in [0,1]$
- $h: = (1-F_2)F_3$
- $F_2'(t)$ and $F_3'(t)$ exist and
- $F_2(t), F_3(t), F_2'(t), F_3'(t) \in [0,1]$
- hence $h:= (1-F_2)F_3 \in [0,1]$

Case 0: (the original)

$$F_{1}'(t)=\dfrac{G_{1}(t)}{(1-F_{2})F_{3}}$$
$$F_{2}'(t)=\dfrac{G_{2}(t)}{(1-F_{3})F_{1}}$$
$$F_{3}'(t)=\dfrac{G_{3}(t)}{(1-F_{1})F_{2}}$$

where $F_{i}(t)$s are unknown CDFs, and $G_{i}(t)$s are known pdfs

Then $h \equiv 1 \equiv (1-F_{2})F_{3}=(1-F_{3})F_{1}=(1-F_{1})F_{2}$

Case 1: $h > 0$ and $h$ is integrable

Then $\frac 1 h \ge 1$.

I think it can be shown that if $\frac 1 h = c_1 \times 1_{A_1} + c_2 \times 1_{A_1}$ for $c_1, c_2 \ge 1$ and $A_1$ and $A_2$ is a partition of $\mathbb R$, then we must have $c_1 = c_2 = 1$.

Then we can extend to simple functions, nonnegative functions and integrable functions. Um, do we need $A_1, A_2$ to be $\mu$-measurable under some measure space $(\mathbb R, \Sigma, \mu)$ ? I was thinking Lebesgue outer measure but since that's not countably additive, perhaps we don't have extension from simple to nonnegative?

Case 2: $h > 0$ and $h$ is not integrable, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb R} h^{+} = \infty$ xor $\int_{\mathbb R} h^{-} = -\infty$

But $h \in [0,1]$ is bounded and hence integrable.

Case 3: $h$ can be $0$
Then choose $\frac 1 h = 5 \times 1_{A}$ where $\int_A f dt = \frac15$

but I'm guessing that the choice somehow defies cdf definitions? Or even if it doesn't, I think there's going to be a problem with dividing by indicator functions. I'm thinking something like $\int_{A^C} \frac{f}{1_A} dt$ with $\int_{A^C} f dt = 0$. Somewhere I came across something like $\int_A f dt = \int_A \frac f h dt = 1$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ and for any $A_s \subset A$, $\int_{A_s} f dt = \int_{A_s} \frac f h dt = 1$ does not hold. Please let me know if I'm making some sense here.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow case 2, $1\in [0,1]$ but $\int_{\Bbb R}dt=\infty$.

Comment: @Surb Ah thanks. I totally forgot the context of saying 'If X is bounded then X is integrable'. That's if X is a random variable. Anyhoo for case 2 we have to make use of $F_2$ and $F_3$ being cdfs?

Comment: Before generalizing can state clearly under what conditions on h you get h=1?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Case 1? Apparently if $f$
 is a pdf and if $h=(1-F_2)(F_3)$ where $F_2$ and $F_3$  are cdf's, then $h=1$. Or do we not have that in Case 1? Edited to include Case 0

Comment: If $h$ has this form then $h$ must vanish at $\infty$. how can you have $h \equiv 1$?